# Example of RasterData class in ArcGIS for Flex

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-flex-api

How would I use the [RasterData](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/tasks/supportClasses/RasterData.html) class in com.esri.tasks.supportClasses for ArcGIS API for Flex? I haven't found any documentation for it outside the API and that doesn't give much info either. Could I construct a RasterData object and use it as a workaround for the limitations imposed upon a client's input parameters for a geoprocessor request to ArcGIS Server? For example,

```
var rasterOne:RasterData = new RasterData();
rasterOne.url = "http://example.com/rasterOne.tif";
rasterOne.format = tif;

var params:Object = new Object();
params.Input_Raster = rasterOne;

var gp:Geoprocessor = new Geoprocessor();
gp.url = "http://example.com/arcgis/rest/services/GPServer/ExampleGP";
gp.submitJob(params);
```

Assume that the GPService has one input parameter, a raster, and does a simple reclassify. Would this work, and would I even be able to publish the GP service with a raster as the input?